# How to give support of switch to old website from updated one?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, web-deployment

I am little bit in confusion about this mechanism. Not sure this is the right way or platform to ask this, but might be I can get some idea at least.

I am working on a web app which has been already live for a long time. I have redesigned whole app with frontend technology of ReactJS and backed in spring boot. As the existing old web app (live web-app) is written in Spring MVC with bootstrap support and which is outdated. Now, we are done with the updated app code, and we are ready to make it live.

Is there any way to give user flexibility to use both web app at same time? Like existing web app which they are using and there will be one button or option from where they can able to get updated UI/UX. And the same thing If they are not feeling well with the new UI/UX they can switch back to old/existing web app.

It is little bit similar like Facebook did a time ago where they give option to "Switch back to classic".

For now, I have one idea in mind to give this support based on subdomain, but not sure is that a good way or technical feasible or not.

Comment: As long as the old and new verison of your app have the same database backing it, a common solution to your problem is (indeed) running 2 separate versions of your app. These can then be ran on separate subdomains (e.g. `old.mydomain.com` and `beta.mydomain.com` or just `mydomain.com`). The switch button would just redirect to the other subdomain. The reason that the backing database of both versions of your app must be the same is because you don't want users to perform operations on the 'old' version and them not being visible in the 'new' version.

Comment: @nbokmans Thanks. I was having same thought in my mind. Do I have to manage anything from the API end? Or this is something to do from front end only? Do I have to take care anything from domain providers?

Comment: Without knowing exact implementation of your old and new project it's hard to say. I can imagine that thinks like authentication would be cookie-based in your old setup (MVC) and JWT-based in your new setup, so depending on how your backend is configured it might handle those kind of things differently. Nothing specifically comes to mind, you'd just have to do some manual testing :)

Comment: You think absolutely correct, as new implementation having JWT based Auth system. Thanks for briefing. @nbokmans